# Git bash shows strange error message on every keypress

Tags: windows, bash, git, shell

After running a shell script, the git bash console doesn't work anymore. Every time I press a key, it returns:

> 29424339 [sig] bash 1962! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 21 to win32 process (pid 18320)

`Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+Z` don't fix the issue. The current workaround is to close and reopen the git bash. Is there a better way? (Unfortunately, I cannot post the content of the shell script here)

Comment: Don't run the script. Or, try running it with its stdout and stderr redirected to /dev/null (or is it NUL on Windows?)

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to open the task manager to directly end all the processes with the Python icon, the actual measurement is effective!

Answer (score 0):

If the language you use is not Python, just close the programming language program used by the current shell. Of course, you can end the related process in the task manager interface, you don't need to close Git Bash, and then Git Bash will return to the console interface.